# Server hangs on reboot when clam is running

Tags: server, reboot, clamav, mail-server

### In a nutshell

Rebooting normally takes under 1 minute, but if `clamav-daemon` is running, a reboot will take 30 minutes exactly.

### Overview

I have a Ubuntu 15.10 "cloud" mail server: postfix, dovecot, mysql, accessed via SSH. This has been working for weeks, and reboots in under 1 minute. All was well, until I installed [Amavis](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixAmavisNew), via Ubuntu's apt-get install packages - now a reboot takes exactly 30 minutes, every time.

When running, everything works. I've checked logs, and no glaring issues. Clamav is working, mail sends & receives, and CPU usage fluctuates between 0% and 0.5%.

### My theory

I've narrowed the problem to the `clamav-daemon` by process of elimination. The only new install was Amavis, which added new daemons. If I stop them all (`amavis`, `clamav-daemon`, and `clamav-freshclam`), then rebooting is instant. If I stop just `clamav-daemon`, rebooting is instant. But if I keep it running and stop all the others, reboot is 30 minutes again.

This is completely repeatable, and the wait is always exactly 30 minutes. This makes me think Clamav is waiting for user input, with a 30 minute timeout.

I can see the processes for Clamav are running with "`--foreground=true`". This makes me think Amavis intentionally does this to capture output, but isn't expecting a prompt during reboot.

From htop:
[image]

### My logs

Note: `/etc/init.d/sendsigs` has `report_unkillable` enabled to catch unkillable processes, and `/etc/default/apport` is enabled. Logs in `/var/crash` have nothing recent.

(Restarted around 14:51, and the server wasn't SSH ready until 15:23 - 30 minutes later, with no errors in between.)

**/var/log/clamav/clamav.log**

```
...
14:52:45 2016 -> --- Stopped at Fri 14:52:45 2016
15:23:04 2016 -> +++ Started at Fri 15:23:04 2016
15:23:04 2016 -> Received 1 file descriptor(s) from systemd.
15:23:04 2016 -> clamd daemon 0.98.7 (OS: linux-gnu, ARCH: x86_64, CPU: x86_64)
15:23:04 2016 -> Running as user clamav (UID 119, GID 127)
...
```

**/var/log/mail.log**

```
...
14:51:15 mail amavis[1578]: Using primary internal av scanner code for ClamAV-clamd
14:51:15 mail amavis[1578]: Found secondary av scanner ClamAV-clamscan at /usr/bin/clamscan
14:51:15 mail amavis[1578]: Deleting db files __db.001,nanny.db,__db.003,snmp.db,__db.002 in /var/lib/amavis/db
14:51:15 mail amavis[1578]: Creating db in /var/lib/amavis/db/; BerkeleyDB 0.55, libdb 5.3
15:23:05 mail postgrey[820]: Process Backgrounded
15:23:05 mail postgrey[820]: 2016/02/12-15:23:05 postgrey (type Net::Server::Multiplex) starting! pid(820)
15:23:05 mail postgrey[820]: Resolved [localhost]:10023 to [::1]:10023, IPv6
15:23:05 mail postgrey[820]: Resolved [localhost]:10023 to [127.0.0.1]:10023, IPv4
...
```

**/var/log/syslog**

```
...
14:52:18 mail systemd[1]: Stopping ClamAV virus database updater...
14:52:18 mail freshclam[760]: Update process terminated
14:52:18 mail systemd[1]: Stopped ClamAV virus database updater.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopped Setup Virtual Console.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopping LVM2 PV scan on device 202:2...
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/758b48d5-df40-4ca8-af0d-a482044d21dd...
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopping Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks...
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
14:52:42 mail systemd[1907]: Reached target Shutdown.
14:52:42 mail swapoff[2140]: swapoff: /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap: swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory
14:52:42 mail systemd[1907]: Starting Exit the Session...
14:52:42 mail systemd[1907]: Stopped target Default.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopping Session 1 of user gavannon.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1907]: Stopped target Basic System.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1907]: Stopped target Sockets.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1907]: Stopped target Paths.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1907]: Stopped target Timers.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Removed slice system-ifup.slice.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Removed slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopping Accounts Service...
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopped Set Cloud Password.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB...
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter...
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopping OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopping Getty on tty1...
14:52:42 mail systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: XenServer Virtual Machine daemon providing host integration services...
14:52:42 mail rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.12.0" x-pid="729" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.

(Something must be happening here, because the next line isn't for 30 minutes)

15:23:04 mail rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.12.0" x-pid="770" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
15:23:04 mail rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ $
15:23:04 mail rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 109
```

The last thing that happens at 14:52 is logging shuts down (`rsyslogd` says `exiting`). The next line is the log starting up again on boot, but that's 30 minutes later!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar issue on a CentOS 7 server (also takes ~30 minutes to reboot) and the thing my logs have in common with your issue is the `swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory` entry. Apparently swap space is disabled at a point during the shutdown sequence when there is not enough free RAM to load the remaining data from the swap space back into RAM. Running fewer services (i.e. not running `clamav-daemon`) probably avoids this situation, which is why you don't see the problem then.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1031158 explains why swap space is disabled during shutdown. The solution is probably to make sure the things that eat the most memory have stopped before swap space is disabled during shutdown. This can probably be solved by specifying dependencies in systemd units, but I haven't figured this out yet.

Another solution would of course be to add more RAM, so that swap isn't used so much. :)

Comment: Increasing the RAM seemed to be the easy fix!